# What steps to follow to create a python environment module? I am trying to do this on Windows 10

Tags: python, tcl, environment-modules

I am pretty new to environment modules and running Python in virtual environment. I could do below steps and stuck on how to proceed further

I have installed the environment module software along with TCL on windows 10. I have followed these instructions https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/INSTALL-win.html

I have Python 3.8.5 installed to a network share S:\Python38

I have created the module file as below. However, when I load it by running "module load mymodulefile" python does not load

```
*#%Module######################################################################
##
##      Python 3.8.5 module
##
proc ModulesHelp { } {
    puts stderr " Python 3.8.5 module"
}
module-whatis "Python 3.8.5"
set is_module_rm  [module-info mode remove]
set BASEPATH /S/apps/python3.8.5WindowsVDI
prepend-path PATH $BASEPATH:$BASEPATH/Scripts*
```

Comment: don't know about that module, but this [may help](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/win/)

Comment: what error message did you get when running `module load mymodulefile` ?